# How to Access Local Storage mails Headers using Pantomime in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pantomime

I am using the Pantomime framework in the cocoa application. I got success fetching the mails from IMAP Server and prepared the Local storage in the form of MBoxes But I am not able to retrieve the mail Headers like To,CC,Subject etc from the Local Storage in my application.
 any help..
Thanks.

Comment: What is the file format you using for creation of Local storage.?